# How do I merge lists of dicts based on dict keys?

Tags: python

Given two lists of dicts:

```
a = [
  { 'some': 'data',
    'foo': 'bar',
    'hash': '0x123456'
  },
  { 'some': 'otherdata',
    'foo': 'foobar',
    'hash': '0x7890123'
  }
]
b = [
  { 'some': 'thing',
    'foo': 'oof',
    'hash': '0x123456'
  },
  { 'some': 'one',
    'foo': 'raboof',
    'hash': '0x7890123'
  }
]
```

How can I "merge" them based on the value of `hash`? I'd like dicts with the same `hash` value put together in a list:

```
c = [
  [
    { 'some': 'data',
      'foo': 'bar',
      'hash': '0x123456'
    },
    { 'some': 'thing',
      'foo': 'oof',
      'hash': '0x123456'
    },
  ],
  [
    { 'some': 'otherdata',
      'foo': 'foobar',
      'hash': '0x7890123'
    },
    { 'some': 'one',
      'foo': 'raboof',
      'hash': '0x7890123'
    }
  ]
]
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Of course it's possible. See how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to group all data by `hash`, it's easier to use `dictionary` to do this in python.

For example, using the two list you provided, you can write code like this:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

# initiate a defaultdict as key-value container for items that has the same hash
container = defaultdict(list)


# adding items to the container
for item in a + b:
    hash = item['hash']
    container[hash].append(item)

# then converting the dictionary items to a list    
c = list(container.values())
```

Comment: I upvoted, but by using `for item in a + b:` you can reduce this to just one for loop.

Comment: @DarrylG Thanks for the advice!